# Windows Scripting: VBScript, DOS, JS, Python, 

Tags: javascript, windows, vbscript, scripting

Say you were mainly a C-syntax like programmer and Linux systems administrator, and you were tasked with creating some simple automation tasks on Windows (monitoring of back-up files, process monitoring, ...). Which language would you prefer to write your scripts in? There's a large collection of VBS-scripts out there (using VB syntax), but I'd prefer anything more C-related.

What are your best experiences in using scripts for Windows? Any obvious down- or upside to a certain language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx).

- It has a vaguely C-like syntaxt.
- It has an integrated shell.
- The newest version (currently in CTP) includes a builtin IDE (Although it is limited compared to other 3rd party ones).
- It has easy access to something like 90% of the functionality in the .Net framework.
- Going forward, MS products will explicitly provide Powershell integration.
- It supports pipes.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much every script in VBS can be converted to an equivalent in JScript.

There are a few gotchas to watch out for. Read up on the enumerator and remember that in VBS is case insensitive so when translating a script, certain methods may have the wrong casing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do what you want to do in a CMD-file, it that doesn't cut it, use Windows Scripting Host to call a wsh-file with JScript and/or VBScript in it. If you prefer the JScript-look, use that as your primary language, and use VBScript for things you copy from the net or cannot find a JScript solution to. You can call VBScript from JScript and the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Microsoft Scriptomatic](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&FamilyID=09dfc342-648b-4119-b7eb-783b0f7d1178) tool too.

It can generate lots of admin scripts in VBScript, Perl, JavaScript (JScript) and Python. Makes navigating WMI **much** easier too.