# Python or PHP for small windows administration scripts?

Tags: php, python, windows, winapi, scripting

I'm choosing between these two languages, in contrast to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546275/windows-scripting-vbscript-dos-js-python). My program going to be set of scripts checking files, free space, checking that apps are running etc. and writing information to database. Then PHP web page will show results.

Python have more examples of winapi calls (at least at StackOverflow) and more attractive to learn and use in different areas of programming, but I didn't use it before. With PHP I have small experience and I will be using it for results web page anyway.

PHP seems to be easier to install on network (to use one network installation for many workstations). Both languages can work with COM objects (I will need ADO).

Scripts will be small, not complex, but their number will grow.

Can someone with experience in similar tasks advise on choice between these two?

Comment: Just search google on the language throw downs and you will find many. Any answer here is going to be mostly a re-iteration of those. Python is quite suitable to do a large number of tasks. So is PHP. PHP is wildly popular for web scripting. Python is wildly popular as swiss army knife. Pick you choice!

Comment: Thanks, pyfunc! I just asked in context of particular task (windows administration scripts). It may be a big deal to install python on network for example. So may be someone will also share his experience on such.

Comment: have a look at `psutil` project for python.

Answer (score 1):

Don't shrink from using a language just because you haven't used it before.  Learning a new language is one of ways to expand your overall capabilities as a programmer.  True, you won't be as productive with it at first but learning how the language tackles common problems (manipulation of data structures, creation and lifetime of objects, etc.) will teach you new ways to think about computing.

That said, I would suggest you use the ActiveState version of Python (http://www.activestate.com/).  It has the Windows integration included.  I'm not sure about network install with Python.  I've installed it across a net by running a remote desktop of the target and running the installer.  Windows wants things registered in the registry so running a language is not like running an .exe sitting on a remote file share.

Answer (score 0):

I asked question first time as anonymous so have no other option to reply now except to write an answer.

Thank you *verisimilidude* for ActivePython advice!

Installed ActivePython at home, reading *Dive into Python 3*.

Installed RadPHP XE at work (company bought it).

So for work it will be PHP. For me, if have free time (and may be for kids, when grew and if interested) it will be Python.

Comment: Just a comment, as Python 3 is "relatively" new and a full non-backwards-compatible rewrite, many libraries are still missing Python 3 support. So you might want to consider using Python 2.7 until version 3 is fully supported by most libraries you could need. Besides that, Dive into Python is a great book.

Comment: And in case you'll ever want to do anything web related with Python, take a look at the fantastic Django Framework: http://www.djangoproject.com/ Also this article is very recommended to read: http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip

Answer (score 0):

As someone who uses both on a regular basis, I tend toward using python for windows scripting and php for web apps.  It's mostly just my preference, but I think they're each ideally suited toward different things.  I love using Python in windows, it is really versatile.

Answer (score 0):

a ) python is a nice alternative because **you can generate an executable**, otherwise (running as script) php is more suitable because it does not required an installation.

b ) try to not to connect directly to the database. Instead, you can create a web page then the clients can connect to it instead to do a direct connection to the database.

for example in php (in the client)

```
  $fp=fopen("http://192.168.0.200/update?id=mymachine&value=200","r");
  fclose($fp);
```

ps: For api calls, both (php and python) can do the same. Thought, for php and Windows Vista (and higher) exist some restriction when you are running it as a apache-module and apache is running as a service but i don't think it is the case.